# Tab Layout in a Fragment

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

i am trying to create a tab layout in a fragment but i am facing an error in creating the ViewPagerAdapter as it cannot resolve method getFragmentManger()
i tried using getActivity but the problem still exist

that is the code for the fragment

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

public static final String TAG = "HF";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: ViewPagerAdapter (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManger) in ViewPagerAdapter cannot be applied to (android.app.FragmentManger)

Comment: You're mixing up regular `Fragment` classes, and support `Fragment` classes. Change the `import android.app.Fragment;` statement in `HomeFragment` to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. Also, make sure all of the rest of your `Fragment`-related classes are coming from the support package.

Comment: @MikeM.post your comment as the answer for people caming here searching for help can find it more easily

Comment: @jonathanrz I've already voted to close the question. You're more than welcome to answer it, if you want, but we really don't need the 500th iteration of "don't mix regular and support `Fragment`s". Btw, you need to put a space after my username - which includes the period/full stop - for me to receive the notification.

Comment: @MikeM. I agree to close the question. Can I vote to close it too?

Comment: @jonathanrz Nope, not yet. You need [3000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to cast close votes.